# MySQLi query not working (not connecting?) even though it just ran one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code, it won't connect to the database right after it runs a successful query. Here is the snippet:

```
    $uresult = $db->query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email='$email'");
    $ures = $uresult->fetch_object(); $ures->uid;
    $_SESSION['ures'] = $ures;
    $db->close();
```

This is right after a prepared MySQLi statement.

Comment: include in the question the full context (the code above the shown code)

Comment: The rest is irrelevant because it works perfectly. The only thing of significance is a prepared statement that is carried out right before this. I don't see why that would impede the new query. I don't mean to sound stubborn, but there is a glaring problem with that snippet that someone more well-versed than I can point out.

Comment: there are cases where a slow query bring the server down and a subsequent query will fail

Comment: $uresult = $db->query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE email='$email'");
    $ures = $uresult->fetch_object(); 
$ures=$ures->uid;
    $_SESSION['ures'] = $ures;
    $db->close();

Comment: If it's not the case with obvious typo from the above comment, you have to see the mysqli error to get the idea what's going wrong